# Compare 3 objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, AngularJS provide function `angular.equals(obj1, obj2)` to compare 2 objects, but I would like to do is compare 3 or 4 objects, AngularJS have any function support it?

Comment: `a === b && a === c`. I just compared three variables.

Comment: Do you need a pure inbuilt angular function?

Comment: @Shin Sang Ki did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    var obj1 = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
  }
  var obj2 = {
    key2: "value2",
    key1: "value1",
    key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
  }
  var obj3 = {
    key2: "value2",
    key1: "value1",
    key3: {a: "aa", b: "bb"}
  }
  $scope.object1 = obj1;
  $scope.object2 = obj2;
  $scope.object3 = obj3;
  $scope.equals = angular.equals(obj1, obj2) && angular.equals(obj2, obj3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <br/>Obj1: {{object1}}
    <br/>Obj2: {{object2}}
    <br/>Obj3: {{object3}}
    <br/><br/>Objects are equal ? {{equals}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(angular.equals(obj1, obj2) && angular.equals(obj1, obj3)){
//threee objects are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you could do, (if you want a fast and dirty way to compare objects), is to convert your objects into strings and make a regular javascript comparison.

```
    var object1 = {
    test1: "aaa",
    test2: "bbb",
    test3: function () {
        return "cccc";
    }
}

var object2 = {
    test1: "aaa",
    test2: "bbb",
    test3: function () {
        return "cccc";
    }
}

var object3 = {
    test1: "aaa",
    test3: function () {
        return "cccc";
    }
}

var isEqual1 = (JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2));
var isEqual2 = (JSON.stringify(object2) === JSON.stringify(object3));
var isEqual3 = (JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object3));

console.log(isEqual1, isEqual2, isEqual3); // logs true false false
```